# Telerik MVC Grid: Conditional row color

Tags: telerik-mvc

In my telerik grid i have a column that has an html.actionlink pointing to a delete function. Now, i dont delete it right away, it stays until the user explicitly says save changes. Is it possible to have the color of the row change depending on a value in the row? So that the user knows which elements are to be deleted?

*Edit*
I will also find it acceptable to be able to have a conditional in the column so that i can detect if the current element has a delete field set to true, set the command text to un-delete or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind. Found the demo for what im looking for
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customformatting?Grid-page=3